# Function gets stuck in infinite loop when input is invalid

Tags: c++, cin

I want to fill an array of the size of 6 with integers from a user input. It checks for an invalid input and also for wether the number is between 1 and 100. It works fine except for when there is an invalid input that is not an integer, in which case it gets trapped in an infinite loop of "not a valid input..". I tried to combat this problem with "cin.clear();" but it doesn't seem to help. What am I missing here?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        cout << "Please enter number " << i ;   
        while (true) {
            cin >> numbers[i];

            if (!cin.fail() && 101 > numbers[i] && 0 < numbers[i])
                break;

            cin.clear();
            cout << "Not a valid input --  please repeat: ";
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `cin.sync()` to clear the `cin` buffer.

code like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int numbers[7];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        cout << "Please enter number " << i << ": ";
        while (true) {
            cin >> numbers[i];

            if (cin && 101 > numbers[i] && 0 < numbers[i])
                break;

            cin.clear();
            cin.sync();
            cout << "Not a valid input --  please repeat: ";
        }   
    }
    for (int i = 1 ;i <= 6 ;++i)
        cout << numbers[i] <<" ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and the result:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -o test && ./test
Please enter number 1: 1
Please enter number 2: a
Not a valid input --  please repeat: a
Not a valid input --  please repeat: 2
Please enter number 3: 3
Please enter number 4: 5
Please enter number 5: 6
Please enter number 6: 7
1 2 3 5 6 7
```